# Raspberry doesn't show the desktop through VNC viewer

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, raspberrypi

I'm trying to connect to my raspberry pi through VNC Viewer. It connects perfectly (it is connected to my router, and I'm able to connect both via VNC and SSH). The only issue that it appears is that it doesn't show me the desktop. What it appears in VNC Viewer is that it cannot currently show the desktop.

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: This is probably because your running vncserver which creates its own workspace separate from your main console session.

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/remote-desktop-sharing-ubuntu-20-04/